# How to add custom field in Journal Audit report in Odoo 11

Tags: report, odoo, odoo-11, journal, custom-field-type

Odoo version: 11

I added custom field to the model "account.payment" : x_mycompany_transcation_id

then I added it to the journal audit report:
[image]

But it shows me the following error when I try to print the report:
[image]

Comment: Please copy code and stacktraces right into the question instead of using pictures. It's hard to refer to anything when there is no possibility to make a copy of it or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

It's only a experienced wild guess, but `foreach` on the table row says `aml` and that usually means that the records in the for loop are of model `account.move.line` which you haven't extended. But instead you have extended model `account.payment`. So you either have to extend the right model or you have to find another way to show the data in the report.

Comment: you are right, I figured that lately, so I created this custom field in the "account.move.line" model and my problem now is how to relate it to the one in the "account.payment" model ? my design flow is :
1. create a payment with custom field 
2. print journal audit including this custom field

Comment: That's not so trivial to get answered in short. Sorry you have to find the relation by yourself :-/